# Compiling Native code (c++) for windows phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have created a cocos2d-x 3.0 RC Project which I wanted to play in windows as well. I have added libraries such as CocosDension, libExtensions, libNetwork, libCurl etc to my project as those are required for the game. When I compile everything is working fine, but when I try to run I am getting the following runtime errors. Below mentioned the is the exception that is thrown.

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   PhoneDirect3DXamlAppInterop.DLL but was not handled in user code. If
>   there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

This particular exception is thrown in below block of code

```
private void DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_d3dInterop == null)
            {
                m_d3dInterop = new Direct3DInterop();

                // Set WindowBounds to size of DrawingSurface
                m_d3dInterop.WindowBounds = new Windows.Foundation.Size(
                    (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth,
                    (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight
                    );

                // Hook-up native component to DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid
                DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider(m_d3dInterop.CreateContentProvider());
                DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundManipulationHandler(m_d3dInterop);

                // Hook-up Cocos2d-x delegates
                m_d3dInterop.SetCocos2dEventDelegate(OnCocos2dEvent);
                m_d3dInterop.SetCocos2dMessageBoxDelegate(OnCocos2dMessageBoxEvent);`
                m_d3dInterop.SetCocos2dEditBoxDelegate(OpenEditBox);
            }
        }
```

Exception is thrown at line

```
m_d3dInterop = new Direct3DInterop();
```

I am also putting the error log below

```
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at PhoneDirect3DXamlAppComponent.Direct3DInterop..ctor()
   at PhoneDirect3DXamlAppInterop.MainPage.DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

If anyone has any idea reg the same, please do help

Answer (score 0):

I'd update the the newly released Cocos2d-x v3 as it has WP8 support.

http://cocos2d-x.org/download

Release Notes: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/docs/RELEASE_NOTES.md